# Full Outer Joins with in Multiple columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I'm trying to join two tables that need to match basically in three different columns but one of the columns might have nulls in both tables. The columns to join will be content_id, user_id and product_id but the products might or might not be the same in both tables. Let's see an example:

Table A

| Content_id | User_ID | Product_ID | Clicked | Saved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 4533700 | 3 | 0 |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 4536767 | 4 | 2 |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 5736767 | 3 | 0 |

Table B

| Content_id | User_ID | Product_ID | Liked | Shared |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 2103700 | 1 | 0 |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 4536767 | 0 | 2 |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 1100046 | 1 | 1 |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 5736767 | 1 | 0 |

I need my final table to look like

| Content_id | User_ID | Product_ID | Clicked | Saved | Liked | Shared |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 4533700 | 3 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 2103700 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 0 |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 4536767 | 4 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 1100046 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 96787244 | 4195813 | 5736767 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I tried to use full outer join USING(content_id, user_id, product_id) but doesn't really work.

Comment: Why doesn't it really work?  What did you get?  That is certainly the correct approach.

Comment: Sample data as 1, 2 and 3 are much easier than 4533700, 4536767 and 4532700.

Comment: I'm guessing you were getting nulls on content_ID , user_ID, product_ID when you did this and didn't want to repeat the field names  for the different tables... so coalesce the values... you need to `SELECT coalesce(TableA.Content_ID,TableB.ContentID) as Content_ID, coalesce(TableA.User_ID, TableB.userID) as User_ID...`    I'll let you figure out product_ID...  as Tim said, your approach is solid.  but your problem is not well defined so we don't know why you're struggling.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for `full join` :

```
select
    coalesce(t1.Content_id, t2.Content_id) Content_id,
    coalesce(t1.User_ID, t2.User_ID) User_ID,
    coalesce(t1.Product_ID, t2.Product_ID) Product_ID,
    t1.Saved,
    t1.Clicked,
    t2.Liked,
    t2.Shared
from table1 t1 
full outer join table2 t2 
    on t1.Content_id = t2.Content_id
    and t1.User_ID = t2.User_ID
    and t1.Product_ID = t2.Product_ID
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=136203bd8035b159c347744d4d6df5cd)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do this.

```
SELECT a.*, b.liked, b.shared
FROM a NATURAL LEFT JOIN b
UNION
SELECT b.content_id, b.user_id, b.product_id, a.clicked, a.saved, b.liked, b.shared
FROM a NATURAL RIGHT JOIN b;
```

We have to enumerate the columns in the second part, because it will naturally select all of `b` first, and `UNION` doesn't line up corresponding columns.

Postgres doesn't accept NATURAL FULL JOIN.  Not sure why.